# Auto click SPAN data-rating class

Tags: javascript, user-interface

Help me click a star

Load a page:

```
<div class="game-rating" data-ajax-url="/rate/image/403632/">
                        <span data-rating="2"></span>
                        <span data-rating="4"></span>
                        <span data-rating="6"></span>
                        <span data-rating="8"></span>
                        <span data-rating="10"></span>
                    </div>
```

When mouse a star 1 :

```
<div class="game-rating rate-1 " data-ajax-url="/rate/image/403632/">
                        <span data-rating="2"></span>
                        <span data-rating="4"></span>
                        <span data-rating="6"></span>
                        <span data-rating="8"></span>
                        <span data-rating="10"></span>
                    </div>

When mouse a star 2 :

<div class="game-rating rate-2 " data-ajax-url="/rate/image/403632/">
                        <span data-rating="2"></span>
                        <span data-rating="4"></span>
                        <span data-rating="6"></span>
                        <span data-rating="8"></span>
                        <span data-rating="10"></span>
                    </div>
```

> star 1 ,2,3,4,5 I have click auto  a star 1 can you help me create a
>   script to tampermonkey ? or javascript ?**

Sorry my bad english

Comment: My code don't working : setInterval(function () {document.getElementsByClassName("game-rating rate-1")[0].click();}, 5000);

Comment: So, when a user clicks a rating, you want the image for the star to change, correct? Should the user be able to change their rating after they choose?